# Reminder text for an iOS meditation app

Tags: ios, copywriting

I wanted to see what your thoughts were on the simple reminder text that comes up when a user has turned reminders on for a meditation app I've built.

As of now it is "This is your reminder to meditate."

I was thinking of something more inline with breaking from the monotony of routine. Maybe, "It's time to meditate."

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your proposed messages look like they could become quite irritating quite quickly.

A computer app can't realistically tell you it is "time to meditate", as it can't possibly know what you are doing at the time.

I suggest something like this:

"Feeling stressed? You last meditated x days ago. Meditation can help you xxx", where the xxx is a randomly selected benefit, like "feel more relaced", "sleep better", etc.

People are far more likely to do something if you give them a good reason to do it. So this needs to be part of the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

**This is a question of voice.** How do you address the user across other channels (website, email, etc.)? Knowing and understand this will help determine the type of voice you wish to use in your messaging within the application.

While I wouldn't consider this a UX question, I understand the potential experience impact.

Short and sweet, use use your imagination - what would you like to hear before you begin meditating?

Comment: Couple points on this:

I'm curious as to why you think this isn't a UX question? and on the topic of UX, isn't the whole point to get beyond what you would like to hear or see, and develop your voice/UI/etc in the context of your actual users and their goals?

Comment: I consider this a Customer Experience problem/question. I see UX as more of the ensuring a user is able to complete their desired task, rather than concerning the voice of the piece.

I'm sure you're referring to my statement where I say "what would you like to hear". I proposed the question as a way of getting the OP to think about his users. When we create personas from scratch, we have to put ourselves into the shoes of our users, right? lol...

But hey, I guess the easier answer would be to tell the OP to stop asking us and invest in usability testing.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Peter Webb's and Ryan Gonzales' answer.

To combine the two, maybe create a table of quotes from zen masters and yogis or something akin to that and do a "fortune cookie" style notification that randomly gives the user a quote followed by a gentle reminder to meditate.

Example: "In order to carry positive action we must develop here a positive vision. (The Dali Lama thinks you should meditate)."

Sourced from: http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/authors/d/dalai_lama.html